# purpose of using quasi likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, quasi-likelihood, quasi-maximum-likelihood

Based on MLE (Maximum Likelihood Estimator), we knew that the puprose is to maximize the likelihood function. Then how about quasi likelihood ? Is quasi likelihood just modelling between mean and variance ?